# Restoring the Order of VBA window

Tags: excel, vba

How to change the order of VBA windows from Horizontal to Vertical.

I have used all the ways to make it correct Deleting files from `RegEdit` or other available thing on google. Is something else is left which can recover/restore the VBA window. Except reinstall the Office.

Any help will be appreciated.

Currently window is in this position.

[image]

I want to bring in this position.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click inside the header of the window, and drag and drop it around. It's not something that needs to be configured in some configuration file.

Comment: I have tried this way but when i open the second module or further it always come in different position not in vertical but horizontal

Comment: In that case: start with VBA, drag and drop until everything is correct, close everything down and restart with VBA. The modifications should be saved in registry and you can continue from there.

Comment: That way is also not working because it does not  adjust the both windows. Vertically, Porject Explorer and Module

Comment: Did you delete the HKEY_CURRENTUSER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\6.0\Common key in RegEdit?